# Get results after Task.WhenAll() call

Tags: c#

`Task.WhenAll(params System.Threading.Tasks.Task[] tasks)` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1) Task, but what is the proper way to asquire task results after calling this method?
After awaiting that task, results can be acquired from the original task by awaiting it once again which should be fine as tasks are completed already. Also it is possible to get result using Task.Result property which is often considered not good practice

```
Task<TResult1> task1= ...
Task<TResult2> task2= ...
Task<TResult3> task3= ...

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3)
var a = task1.Result; // returns TResult1
var b = await task1; // also returns TResult1
```

Which one should I choose here and why?

Comment: You mean you couldn't find [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___)? Your `foreach` loop is processing *individual tasks*, not the result of `Task.WhenAll` (which you are discarding).

Comment: I did edit initial question as it meant to have different method parameters. I am discarding Task.WaitAll result because it only return Task in the overload choosen

Answer (score 6):

If you really have only an `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` and the task will be created `on-the-fly` (e.g. due to a `.Select()`) you would execute your tasks two times.

So, be sure that you either give an already materialized collection to `Task.WhenAll()` or get the result from the return value of that method:

```
var someTasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => { Task.Delay(i * 100); return i; });

// Bad style, cause someTasks is an IEnumerable created on-the-fly
await Task.WhenAll(someTasks);
foreach(var task in someTasks)
{
    var taskResult = await task;
    Console.WriteLine(taskResult);
}

// Okay style, cause tasks are materialized before waiting, but easy to misuse wrong variable name.
var myTasks = someTasks.ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
foreach(var task in myTasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}

// Best style
var results = await Task.WhenAll(someTasks);
foreach(var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

#### Update

Just read this in your question:

> However, I could not find any overload that would return anything but Task.

This happens, if the collection of tasks you give to the `Task.WhenAll()` method don't share a common `Task<T>` type. This could happen, if you e.g. want to run two tasks in parallel, but both return a different value. In that case you have to materialize the tasks and afterwards check the results individually:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskOne = ReturnTwo();
        var taskTwo = ReturnPi();

        await Task.WhenAll(taskOne, taskTwo);

        Console.WriteLine(taskOne.Result);
        Console.WriteLine(taskTwo.Result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<int> ReturnTwo()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return 2;
    }

    private static async Task<double> ReturnPi()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the overload that returns `Task<TResult[]>` - [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___)

Example:

```cs
static async Task Test()
{
    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var currentTask = GetStringAsync();
        tasks.Add(currentTask);
    }

    string[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task<string> GetStringAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "Result string";
}
```